Trying to find why a function is not working
I am trying to figure out what I have done wrong in this code. I'm trying to create a question that will show the user how equal and not equal works in JS, where they can enter two values and pick an operator from a drop down menu. The console log has an error that says: Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '='final.js:21:94. It looks like I possibly cannot put =, ==, or === operators into ${}?


function compareAnswer() {
  let numberInput = parseInt(document.getElementById("value1").value);
  let stringInput = (document.getElementById("value2").value);
  let operator = document.getElementById("operator");
  let answer = document.getElementById("answer");
  let result;
  if (operator.value == "=") {
    result = `Value 1 was ${numberInput}, and is now ${numberInput = stringInput}.`;
  } else if (operator.value == "==") {
    result = `Are ${numberInput} and ${stringInput} equal? ${numberInput == stringInput}.`;
  } else if (operator.value == "===") {
    result = `Are ${numberInput} and ${stringInput} strict equal? ${numberInput === stringInput}.`;
  } else if (operator.value == "not=") {
    result = `Are ${numberInput} and ${stringInput} and has not changed ${numberInput != stringInput}.`;
  } else if (operator.value == "not==") {
    result = `Are ${numberInput} and ${stringInput} not equal? ${numberInput !== stringInput}.`;
  } else if (operator.value == "not===") {
    result = `Are ${numberInput} and ${stringInput} not strict equal? ${numberInput !=== stringInput}.`;
  } else {
    default = "try again."
  }
  answer.textContent = result;
  console.log(`working`);
}

document.getElementById("compareButton").addEventListener("click", compareAnswer);
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="question6">
    <h2>Question 6</h2>
    <h3>Create a value that equals true with one of the operators.</h3>
    <lable for="value">Value 1 </lable><input type="number" id="value1">
    <br>
    <br>
    <lable for="value">Value 2 </lable><input type="text" id="value2">
    <br>
    <select id="operator">
      <option value="="> = </option>
      <option value="=="> == </option>
      <option value="==="> == </option>
      <option value="not="> != </option>
      <option value="not=="> !== </option>
      <option value="not==="> !=== </option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <button id="compareButton">Equals</button>
    <p id="answer">Answer</p>
  </div>
</div>




on the condition before default you have !===  which is not correct syntax, maybe that?

<html> can only have two child elements:  <head> and <body>. Move your script tag to right before </body>.

default is a reserved word in javascript

!=== is not valid and you'll get Unexpected token error on:  ${numberInput !=== stringInput} - at least that's what I get in Chrome, perhaps you're using a different browser so the error wording is slightly different.

"It looks like I possibly cannot put =, ==, or === operators into ${}" - some simple debugging will give you the answer to this.  Remove all the if statements then add them back in one-by-one until you get the error - then you'll know which line is the offending issue and you'll find =/==/=== are all fine (though = is assignment so suspicious here)

default = "try again." -> result = "try again.".

Thank you for all the help everyone, implementing all your suggestions worked!

In js, strict equality is ===, but strict inequality is just !==, not !===.
So you get an error on
    result = `Are ${numberInput} and ${stringInput} not strict equal? ${numberInput !=== stringInput}.`;

which can be
    result = `Are ${numberInput} and ${stringInput} not strict equal? ${numberInput !== stringInput}.`;

Just like == is loose equality, and != is loose inequality. Because = is assignment it was probably designed this way.
